# HTML phone number validation with Parenthesis

Tags: html, regex, validation, phone-number, html-input

How do I validate for a pattern like this...

(562) 810-5566 or (714) 433-4434

Note that it will contain parenthesis and a space.

My current input control looks like this:

```
<input type="tel" data-tel-msg="Invalid Phone Number!" class="k-textbox" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" required />
```

I'm aware the current pattern matches 3334445555, but it's not what I'm looking for, when I tried adding parenthesis the JavaScript console just gave an error incorrect regex syntax.

Also as a bonus, if you know how to get it to display a custom error message that would help also. Currently my data-tel-msg is not working.

Comment: Maybe like this: [`<input type="tel" title="Invalid Phone Number!" class="k-textbox" pattern="(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[-\s]\d{3}-\d{4}" required />`](https://jsfiddle.net/u719637y/1/). BTW, you do not need anchors in a HTML5 pattern attribute.

Comment: just tried your command but didn't work, it might be because of the space? Also any idea how to show custom error messages? Oh just realized 'title' does that, thanks :)

Comment: "It did not work" because you did not say how it should work. What input is considered valid?

Comment: The only input that is valid is (###) ###-####

Comment: It has to have parenthesis and has to have a space after parenthesis

Comment: Then just use `\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}` with the code above.

Comment: you know what I think I just realized the reason I'm getting errors is because I'm in a Twig template which is rendering the javascript via a <script> tag! I have my reasons for doing this because of the Kendo-UI I'm using.  This just complicated things, but your answer is probably the correct answer.  The twig template was ignoring the brackets {}

Comment: It rendered it to look like this, pattern="(d{3})sd{3}-d{4}"

Comment: I think you can double the backslashes. Also, a good workaround for `\d` is `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
 <input value="(555) 324-5643" type="tel" title="Invalid Phone Number!" class="k-textbox" pattern="[(][0-9]{3}[)] [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" required />
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

The regex `\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}` matches strings in `(###) ###-####` format since the HTML5 pattern is anchored (to the start and end of string) by default.

The `title` attribute allows showing error text.

If the backslashes are lost in your environment, just double them, or replace `\d` with `[0-9]`. To match a literal `\(` you can also use a character class: `[(]` (same for `)`: `[)]`). Inside a character class, these `(` and `)` lose their "special" grouping meaning.

Comment: it worked! I changed input to <input type="tel" title="Invalid Phone Number!" class="k-textbox" pattern="\\([0-9]{3}\\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" required />' and now it works

Comment: the character class idea is even better, cleaner and works too